# Proxy server issue setting using GoogleNews api

Tags: python, proxy-server

There seems to be an issue with the office firewall in accessing GoogleNews api. Initially, the code below gave empty results.
I am able to run the below code after I added proxy the environment variable in my user account

http_proxy  http://abcd.mno.com:10023

https_proxy https://abcd.mno.com:10023

I was able to run it successfully both at command prompt as well as on Spyder. My current laptop is connected to work network thru vpn.

Now I wish to set up in another laptop. I hit the same issue. I have set the environment variable in my user account as above. The .condarc file also shows the above proxy_servers. But I am getting empty results. This laptop is in my office, connected to
work network thru LAN

What can I do to ensure the proxy setting is properly configured?

The simplified code that I am using to test that the api is working is as below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
from datetime import timedelta, date
 
googlenews = GoogleNews()

googlenews.search('Corona')

results = googlenews.result()

print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if you have your own HTTP/HTTPS proxy(s) that you want to use to make requests to Google, that's how you do it:

```
gn = GoogleNews()

gn.top_news(proxies = {'https':'34.91.135.38:80'})
```

For more info please refer https://pypi.org/project/pygooglenews/